# Splashscreen image fullsize aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem with setting image to full width and full height with right aspect ratio. I have this piece of code and don't now how to solve it, if it's possible.

Thank you

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="fill">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center|fill_vertical" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using layer-list? You could use a `RelativeLayout` and use the following settings within the `RelativeLayout`

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/your_background_image"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

This `android:background` will put a background image (don't forget to replace this with your own image) and the rest options will make a full size background.

Comment: This code isn't working for me. <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </item>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Becasue I am not Android developer. I am using nativescript and I need to edit just this piece of code

Comment: Try to use the options I gave into your `<bitmap...` cause I see that you already use similar options like `android:src=...`

Also check the following links, it may be a help for your case.

[link-1](https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/creating-launch-screens-android)

[link-2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/8373/followed-splash-screen-guide-but-image-is-stretched-not-centered)